# algorithm to find how many substring in a large numbers range

Tags: algorithm, numbers, substring, dynamic-programming, aho-corasick

I have a problem with this exercice :

Given a range **A** to **B**  with `1 <= A,B <= 10^18`
and some integer representing a substring `Ni` with `1 <= i <= 1000`;
return the total number of possible numbers in the range between **A,B** (including **A** and **B**) that contain any of the given substrings.

**Input**

```
A, B, i 
N1
N2
...
Ni
```

**for example :**

simple Input

```
10 22 2 
1 
10
```

simple output

```
11
```

explanation: the range from 10 to 22 contain the following numbers, `10* 11* 12* 13* 14* 15* 16* 17* 18* 19* 20 21* 22` the valid numbers containing either the substring 10 or 1 are marked with (*)

**How can we compute the total number of possible numbers in the range ?**

Comment: Why does 19 match, but 20 doesn't?

Comment: Explain your example again.

Comment: What is the problem that you have? Is it that you don't understand your assignment?

Comment: Ok, so the third number is the number of strings that follow, not a string itself. That was what confused me. Can you add a question to your question so we know what you're looking for?

Comment: How can we compute the total number of possible numbers in the range ?

Comment: are there any restrictions for Ni?

Comment: @Herokiller 1 <= Ni <= 10^18

Answer (score 1):

First, one need to know Aho-Corasick automation, and also Dynamic Programming.

We divide the problem from range **[A,B]** into two problems **[1,B] - [1,A-1]**

Building the following dynamic programming approach.

```
DP[position][is_equal_to_A][which_node_in_automation];
```

- **position** means length of number
- **is_equal_to_A** means if now equal to prefix of A

Then we just enumerate the last number of current number.